# 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer [python 3.5]

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code to Write an expression for Best(i)

[image]

it shows that 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem with your code, but with the input :

```
int(input())
```

or

```
s=input()
s=int(s)
```

It means that the string which was typed by the user didn't look like an integer.

If you type `"abc"`, `input()` cannot convert it to an integer. If you type `"123"`, it should be fine.

PS: Please don't post screenshots, but code.